# MySQL Query Help, including a count?

Tags: mysql

Any ideas why this isn't working in MySQL?

```
SELECT blogentry.*, 
       person.personName, 
       (SELECT * 
          FROM BlogEntryComment 
         Where BlogEntryID = '8') as CommentCount    
  FROM blogentry 
 INNER JOIN person ON blogentry.personID = person.personID
 WHERE blogentry.deleted = 'N'
ORDER BY blogentry.dateAdded DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery needs to return only one value: the field count. `*` returns all rows, whereas `count(*)` will return how many there are.

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM BlogEntryComment Where BlogEntryID = '8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the aggregate function `COUNT` in order to get the value - `SELECT *` in a subSELECT will frail, because it is attempting to return all the column values for a row into a single column.

That said, what you have will return the same `CommentCount` value for every `BLOGENTRY` record returned.  The following is a better approach:

```
   SELECT be.*,
          p.personname,
          COALESCE(x.num, 0) AS CommentCount
     FROM BLOGENTRY be
     JOIN PERSON p ON p.personid = be.personid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bec.blogentryid,
                  COUNT(*) AS num
             FROM BLOGENTRYCOMMENT bec
         GROUP BY bec.blogentryid) x ON x.blogentryid = be.blogentryid
```

Comment: +1. No idea if it's correct, but generally the queries that I find on SO by high-rep people that I don't understand are 10 times faster than whatever is the "simpler" solution,